# Permession denied error while installing pyldavis in conda env [Errorno 13]

Tags: python, installation, conda, libssl, pyldavis

I'm trying to install `pyldavis` in a conda env using the command `conda install -c conda-forge pyldavis` but I get the following errors:

`ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(700): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::openssl-1.1.1d-hfa6e2cd_0'`

`[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\<Path>\Library\bin\libssl-1_1-x64.dll'`

Comment: Questions about installing software are better asked on [Superuser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: There is a big problem with conda on Windows that we cannot catch for a long time. Under some circumstances conda corrupts files permissions - inherited permissions are gone, users cannot read file anymore, as a result any conda command that tries to read such a corrupted file fails.

Answer (score 0):

Run as Administrator doesn't work.  I was able to fix it by grabbing the same file from another environment and replacing it (kept a backup though).  Hopefully, there are no unintended consequences.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue installing `python-dotenv`. Running the command prompt (or in my case, simply running VSCode through which I normally access the terminal) as administrator fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when installing the sentence-transformers package with a particular file causing the issue: libssl-1_1-x64.dll

Simply tracking down the file and deleting it fixed the problem. When I tried again the install worked with no hitches. I suspect the problem came up when the version needed to be downgraded or upgraded from whatever I have in my base or what some other package had installed. It also makes sense that a security related .dll would cause some extra heartburn.

In my case it was located at: D:\installed_software\anaconda3\envs\nlp-intents\Library\bin where "nlp-intents" is the environment name.